# Web Browsers download html files instead of displaying them

Tags: macos, web-browser

Whenever I try to use browser it automatically downloads the file instead.

It did not work worked in Safari and chrome as well.

How can I get a browser to show the file instead of downloading it?

Comment: what file is it ? what format does it save as ?

Comment: While clicking on any bookmark on web dashboard any files like youtube, email it starts to download instead of opening the URL.

Comment: It saves as Html format

Answer (score 1):

It *may be* that the file association for HTML files has been (accidentally) changed to something else, which tells Safari to download the file rather than trying to open it. I have seen this from time to time and the fix is (usually) pretty easy.

**First,** go ahead and download the files that Safari downloads instead of opening. By default they will go to your downloads folder.

**Second,** click once on one of these files (that Safari just downloaded instead of opening) then go to the file menu and select "Get Info..." A new window should open up that looks mostly like this:

[image: HTML Get Info Window]

**Third,** Look in the screen capture I posted above. Where it says "Open With:" Note that in the pop-up menu "Safari.app (default)" is listed. Find that same menu on the window you just opened on *your* Mac. It likely does not say "Safari.app (default). there" Change it to be Safari.app and click the button just below the menu marked "Change All."

Once that is done you can close that window, Safari should behave better and not *download* HTML files, it should **open** them.

**NOTE** You may have to repeat this procedure with other web pages as some may be saved as ".htm" or ".php" (or whatever) files.